# Unable to kill a process started by win32com.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I am automating an Aspen Plus simulation through its ActiveX client. My code looks as follow:

```
import win32com.client as win32

aspen = win32.Dispatch('Apwn.Document')

# Stuff to initialize, mapping inputs and run simulation

aspen.Save()
aspen.Quit()
del aspen
aspen = None
```

But the process is not killed, still appears in the task manager window.

I tried tu use EnsureDispatch(), pythoncom.CoInitialize() and to kill it with subprocess module. Nothing works. When I force to kill it through cmd:

```
taskkill /im AspenPlus.exe /f
```

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: The process "AspenPlus.exe" could not be terminated with PID 1100.
>
> Reason: There is no active instance of the task.

The issue is that I want these automation to solve an optimization problem, which means I have to run the simulation several times in a loop and it will amalgamate these "instanceless" processes. Each one takes 117 MB of memory so it will collapse.

Any solution to really kill the process inside my Python code?

Thanks in avance!

Comment: so you see the process (with PID 1100) and you're not able to kill it? can you translate the windows error message in english BTW?

Comment: Yes, that is. The message said something like:

ERROR: The process "AspenPlus.exe" could not be terminated with PID 1100.

Reason: There is no active instance of the task.

Also, I am able to kill it from task manager GUI.

Comment: edit your post to change the spanish message. Comments are temporary... do you see the PID in task manager? can you kill with `taskkill /F /PID xxx` ?

Comment: Ok, done! Yes, I can see it and I get the same error message when I try to kill it through PID. Thanks

Comment: can you try `taskkill /F /PID xxx /T` (kills subprocesses too)

Comment: CORRECT: the process with PID 14460 (secondary process of PID 3444) has been finished.
ERROR: the process with PID 3444 (secondary process of PID 1004) can not be finished
Reason: There is no active instance of the task. 

PID 1004 is a system process (svchost.exe). AspePlus.exe is still alive